# Hide error message "No File Chosen" text for asp:fileUpload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to upload a file using `asp:fileupload` control. But I don't want "No File Chosen" or any other such warning text to be shown when no file is selected.
Only selected file name should be shown.

Comment: Post your code and what you have tried?

Comment: uploading is working fine , which is a vb code. I want to hide this "No File Chosen" text.i didn't find any solution till now.

Comment: @RajanGoswami - Can you post the aspx mark-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the code below:-

```
.bar:after {
content:"Please select a file";
background-color:white;}
```

assign it to your FileUpload control. The content message will replace the original one. Of course upon file selection you need to remove the message, you can do this for example via jQuery .removeClass (assuming ID of your FileUpload is "foo"):

```
$('#foo').change(function() {
$(this).removeClass("bar");})
```

Hope it helps